# Get List of all template fields

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have to generate a list of all fields in a template with 3 columns, FieldName, Section of that field, and the name of the template that field is inherited from using Sitecore PowerShell

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/f8d47e8662c51dc7d2ea30e2988fd902 might be a start.

Comment: Yes i have tried this but its not picking up fields from inherited templates

Comment: Show the code that you have so far

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code

```
# Function to get the template from which a field is inherited
function GetInheritedTemplate($fieldName, $template) {
    $fieldItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/templates//*[@@templateid='$($template.ID)']/*[@@fieldname='$fieldName']"
    if ($fieldItem -ne $null) {
        $inheritedTemplate = $fieldItem."__Source".Split('|')[-1]
        $inheritedTemplateItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $inheritedTemplate
        if ($inheritedTemplateItem -ne $null) {
            return $inheritedTemplateItem.Name
        }
    }
    return ""
}

# Get all templates
$templates = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/templates//*[@@templatename='YourTemplateName']"

# Output header for the list
"FieldName`tSection`tInheritedFrom"

# Loop through each template
foreach ($template in $templates) {
    $templateName = $template.Name
    
    # Get all fields of the template
    $fields = $template.Template.Fields | Where-Object { $_.Type -ne "Section" }
    
    # Loop through fields
    foreach ($field in $fields) {
        $fieldName = $field.Name
        $section = $field.Section.Name
        
        # Get the inherited template for the field
        $inheritedTemplate = GetInheritedTemplate $fieldName $template
        
        # Output field details
        "$fieldName`t$section`t$inheritedTemplate"
    }
}
```